# React Native error when passing size of ActivityIndicator as a prop

Tags: javascript, react-native

I was creating a reusable spinner component for my project I had created 2 components: loginform and spinner, where i passed an enum as a prop from loginform to spinner when I reloaded the app it crashed on android but thankfully it displayed an error message on  iOS saying "Error while updating property 'width' in shadow node of type: AndroidProgressBar".

I've tried removing the reference to the prop and instead specified the enum values i.e., 'small' or 'large' to the spinner component. It worked but that completely destroyed the whole point of creating a reusable component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input, Spinner } from './common/';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    state = { email: '', password: '', error: '', loading: false };

    onButtonPress() {
        const { email, password } = this.state;

        this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .catch(() => {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .catch(() => {
                this.setState({ error: 'Authentication Failed!' });
            });
        });
    }

    renderButton() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <Spinner size="small" />;
        } 

        return <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>Log In</Button>;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
                <Card>
                    <CardSection>
                        <Input 
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            label='Email :'
                            placeholder='user@example.com'
                            value={this.state.email}
                            onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                        />
                    </CardSection>

                    <CardSection>
                        <Input 
                            secureTextEntry
                            placeholder='password'
                            label='Password :'
                            value={this.state.password}
                            onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                        />
                    </CardSection>

                    <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>{this.state.error}</Text>

                    <CardSection style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                        {this.renderButton()}
                    </CardSection>
                </Card>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    errorTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'red',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        borderColor: 'white',
    }
};

export default LoginForm;
```

The other component's code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, View } from 'react-native';

// eslint-disable-next-line arrow-body-style
const Spinner = (size) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.spinnerStyle}>
            <ActivityIndicator size={size || 'large'} />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    spinnerStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
};

export { Spinner };
```

I ran the above code and on the expo app on android, it crashed and on ios it didn't crash but displayed the above mentioned error on the red screen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you used "this.props.prop" to access the props, if so, an stateless component doesn't have the "this.props" property, instead you should pass the props like this

In your login screen use this normally

```
if (this.state.loading) {
            return <Spinner prop="small" />;
        }
```

In your component use this

```
const Spinner = (prop) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.spinnerStyle}>
            <ActivityIndicator size=prop />
        </View>
    );
};
```